# change color to #fff on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a href link "Open Menu", and this link have color gray.

I want to use jQuery, for, when I click in this "Open Menu", I want change the color to #FFF.

Im trying to do this with my code below but its not working, I was searching how to do this, but I am having more difficulties because of my icon font element .

Do you see where Im doing wrong?

html:

```
<li class="show_menu"><a href="#sidr" id="hidden-toggle-link" style="position:absolute;top:-500px;">Open  Menu</a>
<p id="menu_toggle" > <span class="change_color" >
   <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
</p>
```

Css:

```
#menu ul .show_menu span >i .change_color{color:#fff;}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {                       
  $("#menu ul .show_menu span >i").click(function() {  
    $(this).addClass(".change_color");     
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the dot `.` for class name that you want to add when using `.addClass()`:

```
$(function() {                       
    $("#menu ul .show_menu span >i").click(function() {  
        $(this).addClass("change_color");     
    });
});
```

Also do not leave space between `i` and `.change_color` in your CSS since space will target the descendants with class `change_color` of `i` elements instead:

```
#menu ul .show_menu span >i.change_color{color:#fff;}
```

Comment: Thank you Felix, it was really that the problem! By the way, now Im always with color:#fff when I click first time in "Open Menu", but I just want to have the color:#fff when the menu is opened. Do you know some trick to do this, to change again for #ccc, when the menu is closed?

Comment: The selector `#menu ul .show_menu span >i` does not actually apply to the "Open Menu" link which I understand is the element to be clicked. Thus this code will not solve the problem.

Comment: @Marby You can use `.toggleClass()` instead of `.addClass()`

Comment: Christian, thanks for your answer! But the code is working fine! And Felix, thank you, I´ll try that now :)